# Graphing $f\circ g$ which $g(x) = ax+b$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, function-and-relation-composition

Consider relation of $f(x)$ is given and $g(x) = ax+b$ . We want to plot $f\circ g $ using transforming $f(x)$. Please explain steps for plotting $f\circ g $ one by one.

Thanks!

Comment: A problem like this is best explored on interactive graphing software, like geogebra. It's amazing how effective it is to _see_ it happen compared to reading about it.

Comment: @ Michael Burr Is this true if we first create $f(ax)$ and then $f(ax+b)$ ? The principle problem to me is order of creating functions.

Comment: @Arthur But I want to do it by hand!

Comment: When I began to work with signal processing this kind of operation was relatively common. Instead of $x$ it was time, but the logic is virtually the same.